# Search the same text in 2 tables then check the cell next to it

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Explanation: I've got 2 tables, one let's say is randomly generated and could contain 5% of the content in the 2nd table or even more. So, the first table let's say has 3 names: Alex, Billy and John, near each name is a fruit: Alex - 2 apples, Billy - 3 pears, John - 5 oranges. Now the 2nd table has many more names, along with Alex, Billy and John. I want to get the numbers and add them to the next table and the type of fruit, also I want it to say that IF Alex has cucumbers he will get -1 from the total amount of fruits and - the numbers of the fruits he already had (meaning that only a group of people could have cucumbers).

In Google sheet, I want it so only the 3rd group (last one) of people from the "Name lists" to be able to have "CT", the rest would get a penalty for it (-1 from total amount and - the numbers from the total number) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n8DF771658l-7lIMu2Jx7YF9ZoHGb3H8UA0eOVd8iaE/edit?usp=sharing

All that is in Project Automation Checker

Comment: Careful @Catalin. Anyone has access to the original file now, the way you've shared it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(QUERY({E2:G}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2),Col3 where Col1 !='' 
  group by Col1,Col3 label sum(Col2)''", 0)-
 N(REGEXMATCH(QUERY(QUERY({E2:G}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2),Col3 where Col1 !='' 
  group by Col1,Col3 label sum(Col2)''", 0), 
 "select Col1", 0), "[^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, C2:C)&"$]")), QUERY({E2:G}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2),Col3 where Col1 !='' 
  group by Col1,Col3 label sum(Col2)''", 0)))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rC5mqpllHQt6OnHNQDkWpLjK4Mz4aYoukR--N7mOxQw/edit#gid=86014782&range=I2)