# Compare 2 tables, find the same text and have it substract the numbers next to it

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

Let's say there are 2 tables, the first one  being randomly generated. The first table has Alex with 10 Apples, Bogdan with 2 pears and Cristi with 5 oranges. In the second table I write that all over, the only difference being that if someone that shouldn't have oranges (only Alex and Bogdan can have them in this case) does, then the numbers of oranges will subtract from the total amount of fruits.

The "oranges" in my google sheet are under the "CT" name and the subtraction will be made in "Project Automation Checker" column J, the only people that can have "CT" are the range named "MDI".

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n8DF771658l-7lIMu2Jx7YF9ZoHGb3H8UA0eOVd8iaE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: whats your question

Comment: How do I compare the 2 tables, see if the table randomly generated and the other one has 2 similar names, then check to see if they have "CT" and are not in the range "MDI", if all that is correct then subtract from the total amount of people that the Host has the amount of people from the "CT"

Comment: how this question differs from your previous one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58167884/5632629

Comment: Well, I don't have to subtract 1 from it now, but this number https://gyazo.com/b69ed57b3ee03c4339a40a4759ec404d and only if the guy is found in the other table,has a "CT" and is not in the range "MDI".

Answer (score 0):

it's really hard to tell what exactly are you after due to no provided examples of the desired output...

---

> The "oranges" in my google sheet are under the "CT" name

```
=FILTER(A1:C10, C1:C10="CT", NOT(COUNTIF(MDI, A1:A10)))
```

[image: 0]

---

> only if the guy is found in the other table, has a "CT" and is not in the range "MDI"

```
=FILTER(A1:C10, C1:C10="CT", NOT(COUNTIF(MDI, A1:A10)), COUNTIF(G1:G10, A1:A10))
```

[image: 0]